# Error code 1 on upload of captured audio file

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I'm trying to implement the media capture code for audio as given on the Phonegap website:

[Phonegap - Media Capture - Audio](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio)

The code opens the device's audio recorder and the file is created as expected. But when I try to upload the file through `File Transfer`, I get the `Error Code 1`.

I have tried using the following code with `fullPath`, `nativeURL`, `toURL()` but nothing works:

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
    }
```

However, it works on some phones which record `mp3` files but gives `error code 1` for `3gpp` or `aac` file formats. I'm trying it on Android only right now.